# Pass variable to view PHP

Tags: php, image, variables, view

I have the following code(see below), which is loading specific folders based on URL, by adding in echo to the line `echo $page[] = $fileinfo->getPathname();` i get the result expected (All the files from the relevant folder) 
I now just need to pass this variable with the pathname to my view so it loads the relevant images:

**Controller Code**

```
public function action_flipbook($page = '') {

FB::log($this->request->param('id1'));
    $this->template->content = View :: factory('flipbook/default');
    // give me a list of all files in folder assets/flipbook_images/.$this->request->param('id1')
    $dir = new DirectoryIterator('assets' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'images'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'flipbook'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->request->param('id1'). DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    $this->template->content->pages = array($page);
    foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
        if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
        //  $page[] = $fileinfo->getFilename();
        echo $page[] = $fileinfo->getPathname();
        }
    }
  }
```

**View Code**

```
<?php
        foreach ($pages as $page) {
            echo '<div><img src="'.$page.'" /></div>';
        }
        ?>
```

By adding **var_dump($page)** `echo '<div><img src="'.var_dump($page).'" /></div>';` i get the array printed like: `array(120) { [0]=> string(37) "assets\images\flipbook\au\1-large.jpg" [1]=> string(31) "assets\images\flipbook\au\1.jpg" [2]=> string(38) "assets\images\flipbook\au\10-large.jpg" [3]=> string(32) "assets\images\flipbook\au\10.jpg"` which is displaying the correct paths?

Comment: You're saving the variable as `page[]` but then using `$pages as $page` when it should be `$page as $pages` or something similar (calling `$page` first).

Comment: i tried that and then get 'undefined variable: $page'

Comment: Assign the var at the end of the method. @BeatAlex this is the var assignation `$this->template->content->pages` so it's actually `pages`

Comment: Apologies. Didn't see that. @RoyalBg

Answer (score 1):

We are not aware of your framework and how assignation is done, but it seems you are doing it like

```
$this->template->content->someVar = 'something';
```

In your case, you have $page as empty param in this method, so I assume until calling:

```
$this->template->content->pages = array($page);
```

$page is empty string so you are building an array of one empty string passed to the view, which will not generate any pages.

Later you do generate array of `$page`, and maybe that's the output you want to pass to the view.

Then you have to move your assignation, after you build the actual array

```
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
        $page[] = $fileinfo->getFilename();
    }
}
$this->template->content->pages = $page;
```

$page is already an array (`$page[] = ...`) so you don't need to put it in one more array.

Comment: yes i want to pass $page to the view, whenever i move $this->template->content->pages = $page; i am getting a error notice of 'Array to string conversion' on echo '<div><img src="'.$page.'" /></div>';

Comment: var_dump the $page variable in the view, maybe it's a nested array?

Comment: If i add in var_dump in the view in replace of just $page, i get an array printed with all my files in, which is correct? Like this: array(120) { [0]=> string(37) "assets\images\flipbook\au\1-large.jpg" [1]=> string(31) "assets\images\flipbook\au\1.jpg" [2]=> string(38) "assets\images\flipbook\au\10-large.jpg" [3]=> string(32) "assets\images\flipbook\au\10.jpg"........

Comment: yep. Nest one more foreach then. `foreach ($pages as $page) { foreach ($page as $pg) { echo " .... $pg .... "; }}`

Comment: thanks! your first method is printing correctly and now i am getting the path displayed in my <img src=""> although it is saying 'failed to load url' im going to try load the image manually to double check the path, i had a problem with the '\' being the wrong way before

Comment: What is the path ? :)

Comment: it should be: /apps/assets/images/flipbook/au/9.jpg however currently it is showing as: \assets\images\flipbook\au\9.jpg so they are the wrong way and also missing the '/apps/'

Comment: can't you preg_replace them from ` \ ` to ` / `

Comment: i've decided on another way if its possible, can i add another 'foreach' like i done before so: `foreach ($pages as $page){foreach ($page as $pg){}} {
    echo '<div><img src="/apps/assets/images/flipbook/'.$name.'/'.$pg.'" /></div>';
   }` and $name would equal `$name[] = $this->request->param('id1');`

Comment: Yep you can :) Try it :) But you have to assign name to the view too

Comment: not working for me :( If i try and change my directory path so without the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` so like `$dir = new DirectoryIterator('/apps/assets/images/flipbook/'.this->request->param('id1').'/');` its giving me an error with the `->` have i done this wrong?

Comment: `$this->request->` you forgot the dollar sign in 'this'

Answer (score 0):

I believe controller code and view code are in different files.

If this is the case then $page will be like a global variable in view file

One thing I noticed that you assign pathnames in $page[] array and iterate through $pages array (there is s at the end)

In view file declare $pages array as global variable and iterate through it. Although this is not the correct way to pass variable from controller to view but you can check if everything is working fine with this technique and than later pass variables as suppose to be passed in Model-View-Controller pattern

```
<?php
    global $page ;
    foreach ($page as $page_single) {
        echo '<div><img src="'.$page_single.'" /></div>';
    }
?>
```